# Distinct statement is used to return only one unique result in one time mysql

Tags: php, mysql

There are three tables:

tblAccommodation table

```
--------------  -----------------------
fldProductID     fldAccommodationName
--------------  -----------------------
```

tblAccommodation table

```
-------------  --------------------  ---------------------
fldProductID   fldAccommodationText  fldAccommodationText1
-------------  --------------------  ---------------------
```

tblAccommodation table

```
------------  --------
fldProductID  seo_url
------------  --------
```

three table join query with distinct

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        DISTINCT 
        tblAccommodation.fldProductID,
        tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle,
        seo_url,
        tblAccommodation.fldAccommodationName
    FROM tblAccommodation 
    LEFT JOIN tblAccommodationText 
        ON tblAccommodationText.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductId
    LEFT JOIN tblProduct
        ON tblProduct.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID
    WHERE
        seo_url = 'yacht-4'";
```

code result

```
------------  -------------------------  -------  --------------------
fldProductID  fldAccommodationTextTitle  seo_url  fldAccommodationName
------------  -------------------------  -------  --------------------
6                 Dolphin Villas         yacht-4     yacht 4 upper cabin
6                 Aqua Suite             yacht-4     Aqua Suite with Pool
6                 Dolphin Villas         yacht-4     yacht 4 upper cabin
6                 Aqua Suite             yacht-4     Aqua Suite with Pool
```

why repeat same value twice please help me

Comment: I speculate that maybe you have some whitespace in some of the "duplicate" records, and hence the four above records really aren't duplicates.

Comment: 3 and 4 record are the duplicate  i think. i want to only two records. ok i'm check again my code.. thank you.

Comment: Try wrapping every column with `TRIM()` and then see if you still get 4 records coming back.

Comment: why not a [group by](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-group-by)?

Comment: Please share sample data of 3 tables and expected result table.

Comment: @Roy group by is work. and i'm remove the distinct ---- thanks all . correct query is there "SELECT tblAccommodation.fldProductID,fldAccommodationText1,tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle,seo_url,tblAccommodation.fldAccommodationName FROM tblAccommodation LEFT JOIN tblAccommodationText ON tblAccommodationText.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID LEFT JOIN tblProduct ON tblProduct.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID where seo_url='yacht-4' GROUP by tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle"

Comment: Nice, can i post an answer to make it the correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GROUP BY](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-group-by)

```
SELECT tblAccommodation.fldProductID,fldAccommodationText1,tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle,seo_url,tblAccommodation.fldAccommodationName 
    FROM tblAccommodation 
        LEFT JOIN tblAccommodationText ON tblAccommodationText.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID 
        LEFT JOIN tblProduct ON tblProduct.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID 
        WHERE seo_url='yacht-4' 
    GROUP by tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

code is work firstly i remove distinct and add after group by function ....

```
correct query is

$sql = "SELECT tblAccommodation.fldProductID,fldAccommodationText1,tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle,seo_url,tblAccommodation.fldAccommodationName FROM tblAccommodation LEFT JOIN tblAccommodationText ON tblAccommodationText.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID LEFT JOIN tblProduct ON tblProduct.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID where seo_url='yacht-4' GROUP by tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationTextTitle"
```

Answer (score -1):

tblAccommodation table

```
--------------  -----------------------
fldProductID     fldAccommodationName
--------------  -----------------------
 6                yacht 4 upper cabin
 6                Aqua Suite with Pool
```

tblAccommodationText table

```
--------------  --------------------- ------------------------ 
fldProductID     fldAccommodationText  fldAccommodationText1
--------------  ---------------------  ------------------------
 6                Dolphin Villas        king sized bed overlooking the ocean...
 6                Aqua Suite            sundeck with lagoon access where you...
```

tblProduct table

```
--------------  --------
fldProductID     seo_url 
--------------  --------
 6               yacht-4 
 6               yacht-4
```

expected table

```
------------           ----------------------------    --------------------  --------
fldProductID          fldAccommodationText1            fldAccommodationText  seo_url 
------------          -----------------------------    --------------------  --------
6             king sized bed overlooking the ocean...     Dolphin Villas      yacht-4
6             sundeck with lagoon access where you...    Aqua Suite           yacht-4
```

Comment: sorry this  is not answer @Sayem  - this is my expected result

Comment: then try this...

`SELECT 
        DISTINCT 
        tblAccommodation.fldProductID,
        tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationText1,
        tblAccommodationText.fldAccommodationText,
        tblProduct.seo_url
    FROM tblAccommodation 
    LEFT JOIN tblAccommodationText 
        ON tblAccommodationText.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductId
    LEFT JOIN tblProduct
        ON tblProduct.fldProductID = tblAccommodation.fldProductID
    WHERE
        seo_url = 'yacht-4';`